# Word for "selectful"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

looking for a proper word to say "only a *selectful* of them", which tries to express that,

- only a *handful* of them, not all of them
- of these a handful, each is carefully selected, not random picked

What would the proper word to use here?

I've found a word "***selective***", but it doesn't sound right to me as it is normally used as "*selective in reading*", or "*someone is selective*".

Comment: A select few, maybe?

Comment: Oh, as simple as that. Sure, I can accept that @MichaelHarvey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for is not “selective” but “selection”:

> ***selection***
>
> the action or fact of carefully choosing someone or something as being the best or most suitable.

So you can say:

> Only a selection of them.